# How to setup glassfish v3?

Tags: 10.04, server, glassfish

There is no package name glassfish or something else related to glassfish.I have to download it to local and unpack the file,but I don't know what to do next,How to start it at startup.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? have you enabled 'Canonical Partners' repository under Software Center?

Comment: ubuntu server 10.04 
The server is a vps.I change the software source  because it can't even install jdk.
My source enabled 'Canonical Partners'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great step-by-step guide here that I just used to deploy GeoServer on Ubuntu Server 10.10:

> http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-301-on-ubuntu

It covers enabling the Canonical Partners repository in order to get the Sun JDK installed,  installing GlassFish and creating init.d scripts to boot the server at startup.  It also provides detailed advice on how to secure the server.

Comment: Here is the new version of the tutorial telling you how to install Glassfish 4.1: https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-41-on-ubuntu

Comment: dead link; invalid.